# How to assign programmatically to SeekBar discrete set of values?

Tags: android, android-widget

How to assign programmatically to SeekBar discrete set of values ? I need to make that SeekBar change values in discrete increments from code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] deltas = ... // set values.
int length = deltas.length;
for (int i=0; i<length; i++) {
    seekBar.incrementProgressBy(deltas[i]);
}
```

If I understand you right.

Comment: Can you answer my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32756044/how-to-set-first-seekbar-process-value-is-to-assign-initial-value-of-second-seek